# Create PDF on-the-fly without storing it on the drive/server and then convert it to type FileBody

Tags: java, file, pdf-generation

I have the following code:

```
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

    //Want this to be on-the-fly pdf creation instead of using an existing one
    File thePDF = new File("/path-to-pdf");

    FileBody fb = new FileBody(thePDF);
    builder.addPart("Body", fb);
    ....Code to use this builder with pdf in a rest callout
```

In the above code I am using an existing pdf file. I want to use a dynamically created pdf instead. I know how to create a pdf using iText, but I DO NOT want to create a new file in the server. Is there a way to store the contents of the file and type cast it to type FileBody or File for use with MultipartEntityBuilder, without actually creating a file on the disk?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments will be more appreciated than a reasonless down-vote. :)

Comment: How exactly are you creating this PDF with iText?

Comment: Using PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
source - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: Ok, so `PdfWriter` creates your PDF in `file` which is file that you can use in `FileBody`

Comment: correct! But that creates a file on the disk, too. Which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, `PdfWriter.getInstance` takes `OutputStream`. Try to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream`
EDIT:
And for `builder.addPart` use `org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141464/discussion-between-reynev-and-user1652925).

Comment: I tried that earlier - FileBody's constructor doesn't like ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating PDF use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baOut);
```

and for building HttpEntity:

```
builder.addBinaryBody(name, baOut.toByteArray(), contentType, filename);
```